# How to create package bundle from yarn zero install packages?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I currently have a monorepo with several packages using yarn workspaces + yarn [zero install](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs). This means we have all dependencies, from all packages installed in a root-level folder `.yarn/cache`

Now, on my CI build, I want to deploy one (and just one) of my packages to a cloud platform, how can I do that? I can run the build for that package, but if I try to deploy it, it won't have its dependencies (which would be in the node_modules folder usually, inside the package).

I'm exploring using [yarn.build](https://yarn.build/), with its `bundle` command, but it's kinda intrusive, as it takes over your `yarn build` and `yarn test` commands, and this messes up the whole project even if I just want the bundle feature. Also, the generated bundle is messy and it has tons of files which are not needed. I wanted something that would kinda "eject" that package from the zero-install structure so it can be deployed standalone.